# minimize number of LOC when using parser.add_option

Tags: python

I am using parser.add_option to my optionparser. What started as 5 options now stands at 13 parameters.
So my code has 13 lines of pasrser.add_option; It also has a long single line of code to check if each option is None and throw a parser.error if any of the required fields are empty.

Is there anyway to make this concise?

Thanks
ps1: I am using python 2.6

ps2:Sample code:

```
usage = "usage:  -b <bname> -a <aname> -c <cname> -d <dname> -i <iname> -t <tname> -r <rname> -k <kname> -s <sname> -e <ename> -f <fname> -g <gname> -u <uname>"
parser=OptionParser(usage)
parser.add_option("-b", "--bname", dest="bname",help="Enter the bname")
parser.add_option("-a", "--aname", dest="aname",help="Is aname required? True/False")
parser.add_option("-c", "--cname", dest="cname", help="Is cname? True/False")
parser.add_option("-d", "--dname", dest="dname", help="Is dname required? True/False")
parser.add_option("-i", "--iname", dest="iname", help="Is iname required? True/False")
parser.add_option("-t", "--tname", dest="tname", help="Is tname required? True/False")
parser.add_option("-r", "--rname", dest="rname", help="Is rname required? True/False")
parser.add_option("-k", "--kname", dest="kname", help="Is kname required? True/False")
parser.add_option("-s", "--sname", dest="sname", help="Is sname required? True/False")
parser.add_option("-e", "--ename", dest="ename", help="Is ename required? True/False")
parser.add_option("-f", "--fname", dest="fname", help="Is fname required? True/False")
parser.add_option("-g", "--gname", dest="gname", help="Is gname required? True/False")
parser.add_option("-u", "--uname", dest="uname", help="Enter your user name")

(options, args) = parser.parse_args()

if(options.bname is None or options.aname is None or options.cname is None or options.dname is None or options.iname is None or options.tname is None or options.rname is None or options.kname is None or options.sname is None or options.ename is None or options.uname is None or options.gname is None or options.fname is None):
     parser.error("-b -v -a -c -d -i -t -r -k -s -e -u -f -g  are all required parameters")
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Am using V 2.6.6 and its not supporting argparse

Comment: Thank you all for your input. Based on all three answers this is what I did. 1) imported module argparse 2) created a list e.g list = [["--name1","-a"],["--canme","-c"]] 3) used a for loop to go over the list and add it to parser e.g for list in a:
 parser.add_argument(list[0],list[1], required=True,help="Is {0} branch required? True/False".format(list[0]))

Comment: Am sorry that I cannot pick one of the replies as the answer. I used a combination of all three. I gave you all points for answering. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Use [argparse](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html) instead of `optparse`:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--bname", "-b", required=True, help="Enter the bname")
parser.add_argument("--aname", "-a", required=True, help="Is aname required? True/False")
parser.add_argument("--cname", "-c", required=True, help="Is cname? True/False")
parser.add_argument("--dname", "-d", required=True, help="Is dname required? True/False")
parser.add_argument("--iname", "-i", required=True, help="Is iname required? True/False")
parser.add_argument("--tname", "-t", required=True, help="Is tname required? True/False")
parser.add_argument("--rname", "-r", required=True, help="Is rname required? True/False")
parser.add_argument("--kname", "-k", required=True, help="Is kname required? True/False")
parser.add_argument("--sname", "-s", required=True, help="Is sname required? True/False")
parser.add_argument("--ename", "-e", required=True, help="Is ename required? True/False")
parser.add_argument("--fname", "-f", required=True, help="Is fname required? True/False")
parser.add_argument("--gname", "-g", required=True, help="Is gname required? True/False")
parser.add_argument("--uname", "-u", required=True, help="Enter your user name")

args = parser.parse_args()
```

---

With argparse:

- You don't need to specify the `dest` parameter. By default, the
  `dest` value is set to the long option name of the parameter. (For example, `"--bname"` causes `dest` to be set to `bname`, and value of the option can be accessed as `args.bname`.)
- You don't need to use the huge `if` statement; just set
  `required=True`.

---

Argparse is compatible with all Python versions >= 2.3. It is [easy to install](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/argparse) even without admin privileges. The comprehensive solution to local installation would be to use [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv), but if you don't want to go to that length, argparse can be installed by simply placing argparse.py in any directory listed in your PYTHONPATH.

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to shorten this code; e.g. you can replace all the variants of

```
parser.add_option("-a", "--aname", dest="aname", help="Is aname required? True/False")
```

with a loop

```
for c in "aitrksefg":
    parser.add_option("-%s" % c, "--%sname" % c, dest="%sname" % c,
                      help="Is %sname required? True/False" % c)
```

As Edsger Dijkstra said, "two or more? use a `for`".

As for the expression

```
(options.bname is None or options.aname is None or options.cname is None or options.dname is None or options.iname is None or options.tname is None or options.rname is None or options.kname is None or options.sname is None or options.ename is None or options.uname is None or options.gname is None or options.fname is None)
```

that can be abbreviated

```
None in (options.bname, options.aname, ...)
```

or even further

```
None in (getattr(options, "%sname" % c) for c in "bacditrkseugf")
```

although you don't actually need it, as unutbu has pointed out.

Comment: Thanks for your input. How I do this if I were to use a list instead of for loop?

Comment: Also in your for loop example,how can I make %s work, when name is not as straight forward as aname, bname etc and are totally unique like apple, orange etc?

Comment: One way or other you have to make a list of the names, e.g `['apple','orange','two','anma']`.

Answer (score 1):

This bit of code constructs the usage and options, as well as the test from a simple list of letters.  It is just straight forward Python use of loops to perform repetitive tasks.

```
from optparse import OptionParser

alist = list('abcdef')

usage = ['usage: ']
for a in alist:
    usage.append('-%s <%sname>'%(a,a))
usage = ' '.join(usage)
# could also be written as a comprehension

parser = OptionParser(usage)
for a in alist:
    parser.add_option('-%s'%a, '--%sname'%a, dest='%sname'%a,help='%s help'%a)

(options,args) = parser.parse_args()

errormsg = usage  # just to keep things simple for this example
for a in alist:
    if getattr(options,'%sname'%a) is None:
        parser.error(errormsg)
print options
```

`argparse.py` can be downloaded and used with pre 2.7 Python.  The main advantage is that `argparse` can handle the usage and error tests for you.